# PHP - In "===" what is evaluated first? Either type or value equality?

Tags: php

We have a comparison operator which has a operator '==='. Can someone guide, what is evaluated first, the "type" or the value equality?

Comment: My Anxiety, and there must be a precedence

Comment: Common sense says, type first.

Comment: Well, in that case, Common Sense Should be renamed as "Super Power"....

Comment: Also, get this in your bookmarks http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's the Type,
normally when you use the `==` operator ,

1. it will check the type first, if they are different it will convert one of them to be identical,
2. then it will check if the values are equals,

so always the **Type** will be evaluated first.

**EDIT**

**Referring to artragis answer**
below is the full source code of the `is_identical_function` php 5.4.8  ( thanks to artragis )

```
ZEND_API int is_identical_function(zval *result, zval *op1, zval *op2 TSRMLS_DC) /* {{{ */
    {
        Z_TYPE_P(result) = IS_BOOL;
        if (Z_TYPE_P(op1) != Z_TYPE_P(op2)) {
            Z_LVAL_P(result) = 0;
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        switch (Z_TYPE_P(op1)) { // here it will check the Type and below it will check the value
            case IS_NULL:
                Z_LVAL_P(result) = 1;
                break;
            case IS_BOOL:
            case IS_LONG:
            case IS_RESOURCE:
                Z_LVAL_P(result) = (Z_LVAL_P(op1) == Z_LVAL_P(op2));
                break;
            case IS_DOUBLE:
                Z_LVAL_P(result) = (Z_DVAL_P(op1) == Z_DVAL_P(op2));
                break;
            case IS_STRING:
                Z_LVAL_P(result) = ((Z_STRLEN_P(op1) == Z_STRLEN_P(op2))
                    && (!memcmp(Z_STRVAL_P(op1), Z_STRVAL_P(op2), Z_STRLEN_P(op1))));
                break;
            case IS_ARRAY:
                Z_LVAL_P(result) = (Z_ARRVAL_P(op1) == Z_ARRVAL_P(op2) ||
                    zend_hash_compare(Z_ARRVAL_P(op1), Z_ARRVAL_P(op2), (compare_func_t) hash_zval_identical_function, 1 TSRMLS_CC)==0);
                break;
            case IS_OBJECT:
                if (Z_OBJ_HT_P(op1) == Z_OBJ_HT_P(op2)) {
                    Z_LVAL_P(result) = (Z_OBJ_HANDLE_P(op1) == Z_OBJ_HANDLE_P(op2));
                } else {
                    Z_LVAL_P(result) = 0;
                }
                break;
            default:
                Z_LVAL_P(result) = 0;
                return FAILURE;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: @AD7six I mentioned in my edit `thanks to artragis`, and this is not the same code I mentioned above that is for the 5.4.8 which different for  previous version

Answer (score 7):

### Type first

The type check is first. It is not possible to compare variables of different types *without* first casting them both to the same type.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is the type because `===`does equalty without conversion but sometimes values are coded identically like "0" and "false". As 0 !== false I think the first thing tested is type.

According to [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.c) :

```
ZEND_API int is_identical_function(zval *result, zval *op1, zval *op2 TSRMLS_DC) /* {{{ */
{
  Z_TYPE_P(result) = IS_BOOL;
  if (Z_TYPE_P(op1) != Z_TYPE_P(op2)) {
     Z_LVAL_P(result) = 0;
     return SUCCESS;
  }
  /*then value check*/
```

Comment: Thanks Artagis for the reference

Answer (score -1):

The operator checks if the internal object id is the same.
Say, You have 2 instances of of class Foo { var $bar = 0}, even if the objects are of the same type, and have the same value, they are not the same object, and thus === will return false.

For primitives, both type and value have to be exactly the same. Order does not matter. It's logical AND.